# Image source is an eval but I need it to disappear completely if eval is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code on my C# page (web-based store):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Width="65" Visible="true">
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="columnHeader gradient" ForeColor="Black" />
    <ItemTemplate>        
        <img src='<%#GetSecureThumbnailUrl(Eval("Product"))%>' width="65px" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and `GetSecureThumbnailUrl` is like this:

```
public string GetSecureThumbnailUrl(object product)
{
    string secureUrl;

    Product this_product = (Product)product;
    if (this_product != null)
    {
        secureUrl = this_product.ThumbnailUrl.Replace("http:", "https:");
        return (secureUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return("");
    }
}
```

My issue is:  The page has an `<img>` tag with no valid graphic source so it displays as a broken image.

My question is:  How do I make the img disappear completely if GetSecureThumbnailUrl resolves to the "" return?

Since it's in a Template it's not clear to me... although I feel like it should be.

Thanks!
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this method twice - once for the source link itself, and one for visibility check:

```
<img src='<%#GetSecureThumbnailUrl(Eval("Product"))%>'
     width="65px"
     runat="server"
     Visible='<%#GetSecureThumbnailUrl(Eval("Product")) != null%>' />
```

Or you can define a single simplified function specially for visibility:

```
public string ShowThumbnail(object product)
{
    string secureUrl;

    Product this_product = (Product)product;
    return (this_product != null)
}


<img src='<%# GetSecureThumbnailUrl(Eval("Product")) %>'
     width="65px"
     runat="server"
     Visible='<%# ShowThumbnail(Eval("Product")) %>' />
```

Comment: See, I knew it should be obvious! :)   Thanks for the quick answer!